# VMWare Horizon Client Scrambles Keystrokes

Tags: vmware

I am using VMWare Horizon Client to connect to a remote virtual computer and intermittently keystrokes get scrambled when I am typing. It occurs in a regular pattern, about every 90 seconds. For 5 seconds nothing I am typing appears, then my keystrokes appear in a sequence similar to this:

I type:

```
abcdefghijk
```

This appears:

```
defghijkabc
```

Version: 3.4.0 build-2769709
Connect via: PCoIP (my only option)

Any ideas?

Comment: We need more information about the software being used. Verify all software is using the same keymap.

Comment: The problem is temporal, not a keymap. Typing works normally in all applications most of the time, but every minute or two there is a lag in response, and the keystrokes appear out of order.